# How to print elements right under the other equaly?

Tags: python, printing, format

I want to have all the elements of the second column straight under the title Index.

```
 for i in range(len(common_e)):
    os.system('cls')
    print('------------------------------------')
    print('Type\t\tIndex')
    print('------------------------------------')
    for j in range(len(types)): print(types[j][0],types[j][1],sep='\t')
    print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Here's my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd8Zt.png)

Thank you.

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: use the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) module

Comment: This is the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd8Zt.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the \t tab character you can use format specifiers. The -10 part means that the text is left-justified with 10-len(types[j][0]) spaces after the string so you can adjust this value accordingly. Hope this helps!

```py
print("%-10s %d" % (types[j][0], types[j][1]))
```